# python (Pandas) output value from column 0 based on criteria different columns meet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, range

I have two pandas dataframes, dfA and dfB. 
dfA has an unknown, say x, number of columns. dfB is a numpy array with x – 1 number of values. So, if dfA has 50 columns (0 to 49), then dfB will have 49 values. These 49 values are associated with dfA columns 1-49.

From column 0 of dfA I need output the value from the row that’s closest to the corresponding value in dfB in the subsequent columns. I know that sentence makes no sense. Here’s an example:

```
dfA:                
0   0.02    0.06    0.09    0.10
1   0.92    0.82    0.71    0.61
2   0.92    0.82    0.72    0.62
3   0.94    0.84    0.74    0.64
4   0.96    0.86    0.76    0.66
5   0.98    0.88    0.78    0.68


dfB:                
    0.94    0.862   0.732   0.623


Answer: 3   4   3   2
```

I’ve been trying to do this using either the pandas query function or loc/iloc features but haven’t managed to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using NumPy -

```
a = df.values
out = a[np.abs(a[:,1:] - dfB.values.ravel()).argmin(0),0]
```

Basically, we subtract `dfB` from each row of `dfA` and since we are working with NumPy arrays (as we had extracted those with `.values`), these are subtracted efficiently in a [`broadcasted manner`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Then, we find absolute values and look for arg-minimum along each column with `.argmin(axis=0)`, in short `.argmin(0)`.

If you are working with `NaNs` as well, use `np.nanargmin` to ignore those.

Step by step sample run to make things easier to understand -

```
# Extract array from dfA
In [9]: a = dfA.values

# Slice a from col-1 onwards and perform broadcasted differencing with dfB values
In [10]: a[:,1:] - dfB.values.ravel() 
Out[10]: 
array([[-0.92 , -0.802, -0.642, -0.523],
       [-0.02 , -0.042, -0.022, -0.013],
       [-0.02 , -0.042, -0.012, -0.003],
       [ 0.   , -0.022,  0.008,  0.017],
       [ 0.02 , -0.002,  0.028,  0.037],
       [ 0.04 ,  0.018,  0.048,  0.057]])

# Get absolute values
In [11]: np.abs(a[:,1:] - dfB.values.ravel()) 
Out[11]: 
array([[ 0.92 ,  0.802,  0.642,  0.523],
       [ 0.02 ,  0.042,  0.022,  0.013],
       [ 0.02 ,  0.042,  0.012,  0.003],
       [ 0.   ,  0.022,  0.008,  0.017],
       [ 0.02 ,  0.002,  0.028,  0.037],
       [ 0.04 ,  0.018,  0.048,  0.057]])

# Look for argmin along each col
In [14]: idx = np.abs(a[:,1:] - dfB.values.ravel()).argmin(axis=0) 

In [17]: idx
Out[17]: array([3, 4, 3, 2])

# First col from a
In [15]: a[:,0] 
Out[15]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])

# Index into first col with those indices to select the desired output values
In [16]: a[idx,0] 
Out[16]: array([ 3.,  4.,  3.,  2.])
```

Comment: Hmmm, maybe mainly difference in timings because `NaN` handling... What do you think?

Comment: @jezrael I would think its just the way its faster with arrays, I guess? Nan handling could be resolved with `np.nanargmin()`.

Comment: @jezrael Does pandas use `broadcasting` for these subtractions, if you happen to know?

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm getting an error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (51,1) (20,52) .
Something wrong with the dataframes im using?

Comment: @BioProg Ah! I think you need to use : `np.abs(dfA.values[:,1:] - dfB.values).argmin(0)` instead to skip that first column from `dfA`. Check that out?

Comment: Getting the same error. I'm going to try it out on a simpler dataset and get back to you.

Comment: @BioProg Ah I think I know! Try this : `np.abs(dfA.values[:,1:] - dfB.values.ravel()).argmin(0)`.

Comment: It's no longer giving me an error but the numbers make no sense. The numbers are larger than those in the column 0 of dfA. Would you expect the output to be the row number of column 0 or the actual value?

Comment: @Divakar  Just tried it, same result. The numbers are larger than any number in either of the dataframes. And yep, I need to use the second column onwards in dfA. But the answer is from the first column of dfA. It seems to have worked in the small example in your first post, right. Not sure why it woulddnt translate to a bigger dataset.

Comment: @BioProg Well the answer from my proposed solution code should be elements from the first column of `dfA`. I am not sure how it could be anything outside of it. I made an edit in the post to use the first column with : `out = a[np.abs(a[:,1:] -....,0]` , just making sure you are using the latest solution code.

Comment: @Divakar This works! I was doing something ridiculous to the dataframes upstream of your code, you last suggestion [np.abs(a[:,1:] - dfB.values.ravel()).argmin(0),0] works. Thank you, you've saved me a lot of time. Could you please briefly explain what your code does?

Comment: @BioProg Glad it worked for you! Added a step by step sample run to make things easier to understand. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Substract values of `array dfB` from `dfA` by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html), get absolute values by [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html) and last find `index` of minimal values by [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html):

```
print (dfA.sub(dfB, axis=1).abs().idxmin())
1    3
2    4
3    3
4    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for this, jezrael. The output is all NaN. There are no NaN's in dfA or dfB.